# CSS: Changing select - option font-size if appearance:none

Tags: html, css

So, basically I turned off native select box styling with

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

so I can have my own caret icon.

Now, what I would like to accomplish is select box having one size
and option having bigger font size

something like:

```
select.micro{
    font-size: 12px;
}

select.micro option{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I cannot seem to make it work... whatever I do... both seem to be connected and I cannot change size just for the option without affecting the select box itself (when it's closed to be clear)

Comment: The fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/77bpshbo/1/ displays the two different font sizes for me in Chrome (v.52.0.2743.116 m). Could this be a browser-based issue, a typo somewhere in your code or a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: sadly I have access only on chrome v40x.... both sizes are the same for me :/

Comment: You could try wrapping your options in an optgroup and styling that. The trouble is, you then get indentation on the items

Comment: well, I gave up... will do somewhat of a hybrid... boostrap's dropdown for desktop and native select for mobile... gives much more flexibility and consistency ;) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to be sure `appearance` works on every browser.

and this is for IE ( works like `appearance:none` ) :

```
select::-ms-expand {
display: none;
}
```

( tested in Chrome , Firefox, Safari )

if it still doesn't work, use `!important` on `select.micro option { font-size:16px!important}` . i would recommend it only as a last resort.

```css
select { 
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:none;
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

select.micro {
  font-size: 12px;
}

select.micro option {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<select class="micro">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```